# Detecting incoming call on Sim1 or Sim2 on android DUAL SIM phone

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how can one programmatically determine if the incoming call is on SIM1 or SIM2. A solution which is a generic one.

What done so far:
Able to get incoming call number using

`String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)`

But unable to find whether this call is for SIM1 or SIM2.

BroadcastReceiver code is as follows :

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            if ((number != null)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Answered " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Idle "+ number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Permissions requested in Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share a bit more info on how you're doing this. What's your intent receiver, for instance? Then we can talk about what info could be in the intent.

Comment: In order to solve this you'll probably need to get some ID from the intent and query the TelephonyManager for the device / slot, and figure out which SIM it is. I don't know of a direct way to get that info (but someone else might know).

Comment: @Stan, thanks for offering help. I have added code snippet in question now. 

we are not getting any other parameter in intent.getExtras() other then state and number.